# K means clustering of variable with multiple values

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means, mean

I have a sample data below that is from a large data set,  where each participant is given multiple condition for scoring.

```
Participant<-c("p1","p1","p2","p2","p3","p3")
Condition<-c( "c1","c2","c1","c2","c1","c2")
Score<-c(4,5, 5,7,8,2)
T<-data.frame(Participant, Condition, Score)
```

I am trying to use K-mean clustering to split participants in different groups, is there any good way to do it, considering the condition is not numeric?

thanks!

Comment: This would be much better in http://stats.stackexchange.com/ aka CrossValidated

Comment: But in the meantime, You could use a variant of KMeans that doesn't use Euclidean distance - Manhattan distance might be appropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Anony has the right idea. You actually do have numeric data - there is (evidently) a c1-score and a c2-score for each participant. So you need to convert your data from "long" format (data in a single column (`Score`) with a second column (`Condition`) differentiating the scores, to "wide" format (scores under different conditions in separate columns). Then you can run kmeans clustering on the scores to group the participants.

Here is how you would do that in R, using a slightly larger example to demonstrate the clusters.

```
# example with 100 Participants in 3 clusters
set.seed(1)    # for reproducibble example
T <- data.frame(Participant=rep(paste0("p",sprintf("%03i",1:100)),each=2),
                Condition  =paste0("c",1:2),
                Score      =c(rpois(70,c(10,25)),rpois(70,c(25,10)),rpois(60,c(15,10))))
head(T)
#   Participant Condition Score
# 1        p001        c1     8
# 2        p001        c2    25
# 3        p002        c1     7
# 4        p002        c2    27
# 5        p003        c1    14
# 6        p003        c2    28
library(reshape2)   # for dcast(...)
# convert from long to wide format
result <- dcast(T,Participant~Condition,value.var="Score")
# k-means on the columns containing scores - look for 3 clusters
result$clust <- kmeans(result[,2:ncol(result)],centers=3)$clust
result[sample(1:100,6),]    # just a random sample of 6 rows
#    Participant c1 c2 clust
# 12        p012 13 21     1
# 24        p024  7 32     1
# 85        p085 10  6     2
# 43        p043 27  5     3
# 48        p048 29 11     3
# 66        p066 24 17     3
```

Now we can plot the scores, showing how the participant clusters.

```
# plot the scores for each Participant, color coded by cluster.
plot(c2~c1,result,col=result$clust, pch=20)
```

[image]

**EDIT**: Response to OP's comment.

OP wants to know what to do if there is more than one score for a participant/condition. The answer depends on *why* there are multiple scores. If the replicates are random and have a central tendency, then probably taking the mean is justified, although in theory participants with more replicates should be more heavily weighted.

One the other hand, suppose these are test scores. Then generally (but not always), the scores go up with multiple sittings. So these scores would *not* be random - there is a trend. In that case it might be more meaningful to take the most recent score.

As a third example, if the scores are used to make a decision based on some policy (such as with the SAT, where most colleges use the highest score), then the most appropriate aggregating function might be max, not mean.

Finally, it might be the case that the *number of replicates* is in fact an important distinguishing characteristic. In that case you would include not just the scores but also the number of replicates for each participant/condition when clustering. This is relevant in certain kinds of standardized testing under NCLB, where students take the test over and over again until they pass.

BTW: This type of question (the one in your comment) *definitely* belongs on https://stats.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Excellent! Just one more thing. In my actual data set, If Each participant has multiple scores for each condition. then I should calculate the mean score per condition and apply the method above,is this correct way to deal with this kind of situation?

Answer (score 2):

You should **pivot** your data, so that

1. each participant is a row
2. each condition is a column
3. the scores are your data

Try the `reshape2` package.

Comment: Do you mean `reshape2` package perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 variables which will be used to split your data in groups. Two of them are categorical which might cause a problem. You can use k-means to split your data in groups but you will need to make dummies for your categorical data (condition and participant) and scale your continuous variable Score.

Using categorical data in K-means is not optimal because k-means cannot handle them well. The dummies will be highly correlated which might cause the algorithm to put too much weight on them and produce suboptimal results.

For the reason above, you can use different techniques such as hierarchical clustering or running a PCA on your data (in order to have continuous uncorrelated data) and then perform a normal k-means model on the PC scores.

These links give good answers:
[link1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58910/kmeans-whether-to-standardise-can-you-use-categorical-variables-is-cluster-3)
[link2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68291/is-it-ok-to-use-correlated-variables-for-cluster-analysis)

Hope that helps!